# How to reduce the thickness of line in number picker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have tried to reduce the thickness of horizontal line in Number Picker but its not working.So i want to know how to reduce the thickness of line in Number Picker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a try as follow:

```
private void setNumberPickerDivider(NumberPicker picker) {
        Field[] fields=NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f:fields){
            if(f.getName().equals("mSelectionDividerHeight")){
                f.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                f.set(picker,1);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this attribute on xml

`android:selectionDividerHeight="0.5dp"`

Comment: Worked for me though.